# Make Tabs centered on HTML page CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get tabs centered on a page. 
 I've tried align="center" in the div, also tried position: center; in the css.

I cant seem to get it to centered.

NOTE:I do not want to use position: absolute; 
This is the code I have now

```css
  .tab-links li {

    margin: 0px 5px;

    float: center;

    list-style: none;

    position: center;

    display: inline-block;

  }

  .tab-links a {

    padding: 9px 15px;

    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;

    background: #D3D3D3;

    font-size: 16px;

    font-weight: 600;

    border: 1px solid black;

    transition: all linear 0.15s;

    text-align: center;

    width: 150px;

    float: center;

  }

  .tab-links a:hover {

    background: #a7cce5;

    text-decoration: none;

  }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">

    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Listing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Bidding</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Log Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
```

Any suggestions of how I could make it centered.

Thanks

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't do anything.

Comment: what elements exactle are you trying to center?

Comment: Trying to get the div  centered, so all the tabs are centered on the page.

Comment: There is no such thing as `float:center` your options are `left`, `right` and `clear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following to your CSS:

```
.tabs{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fatuhu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `display: table`; and `margin: 0 auto`;

```css
.tabs {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tab-links li {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  float: center;
  list-style: none;
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab-links a {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  float: center;
}
.tab-links a:hover {
  background: #a7cce5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">

    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Listing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Bidding</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Log Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```